# Azure Search - Creating a dedicated search table in SQL, for using with an Indexer

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I'm building an Assets search engine. 
The data I need to be indexed for each assets is scattered into multiples tables in the SQL database.
Also, there is many events in the application that will trigger update to the asset indexed fields (in Draft, Rejected, Produced, ...).

I'm considering creating a new denormalized table in the SQL database that would exist solely for the Azure Search Index.
It would be an exact copy of the Azure Search Index fields.
The application would be responsible to fill and update the SQL table, through various event handlers.
I could then use an Azure SQL Indexer schedule to automatically import the data into the Azure Search Index.

PROS:

- We are used to deal with sql table operations, so the application code remains standard, no need to learn the Azure Search API
- Both the transactional and the search model are updated in the same SQL transaction (atomic). Then the Indexer update the index in an eventual consistent manner, and handle the retry logic.
- Built-in support for change detection with SQL Integrated Change Tracking Policy

CONS:

- Indexed data space usage is duplicated in the SQL database
- Delayed Index update (minimum 5 minutes)

Do you see any other pros and cons ?

**[EDIT 2017-01-26]**

There is another big PRO for our usage.

During development, we regularly add/rename/remove fields from the Azure index. In its current state, some schema modifications to an Azure Index are not possible, we have to drop and re-create the index.

With a dedicated table containing the data, we simply issue a Reset to our indexer endpoint and the new index gets automatically re-populated.

Comment: Azure Search indexers offer eventual consistency - the data from your table will make it to Azure Search index, but as you pointed out, there's a delay. Calls to Azure Search can also fail - they will be retried per your indexer schedule, but  thee behavior is certainly not transactionally consistent. On the other hand, your code only needs to do one thing (update the table), and Azure Search will take care of pulling the changes - maybe that's what you mean by "same transaction"?

Comment: Yes that is what I meant. Should have used eventually consistent. And the retry logic being handled by the indexer. Having to call directly the API, I would have to build myself the logic for being eventually consistent.

Comment: Guys I am facing the same issue. Is the above suggested approach the best ? Or creating views and adding a soft delete column also an option ?